# WebSocket onmessage() not being called when messages are sent

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I'm using autobahn 0.4.10 (https://github.com/oberstet/Autobahn) as a WebSocket server to send messages to a Google Chrome Extension.  I am able to open and close connections using `WebSocket()`, but when I call `autobahn.websocket.WebSocketServerProtocol.sendMessage()` the message appears to be sent but isn't delivered until the connection is closed.

The api for WebSocketServerProtocol's `sendMessage()` (derived from WebSocketProtocol) can be found here: http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn/doc/python/websocketprotocol.html#autobahn.websocket.WebSocketProtocol

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

The code I have been on the client side is (js):

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4444');
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log('hii');
}
```

And on the server (python)...

```
#json is a string object
def sendEvent(self, json):
    print 'to', self.peerstr
    self.sendMessage(json, sync=True)
```

Both Autobahn and my version of Chrome (17.0.963.46) appear (from what I've gotten out of the headers and docs) to use version 13 of the WebSocket draft protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a threading problem with some threads block the twisted reactor.

See:
http://groups.google.com/group/autobahnws/browse_thread/thread/6bf0c43ec169efc3#
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

Autobahn works with Chrome (tested up to v19 .. Canary).

Could you try the

https://github.com/oberstet/Autobahn/blob/master/demo/broadcast/broadcast_server.py

demo to see if you have a general issue?

If that runs, direct your extension to that demo server .. it'll send you 1 tick per sec.

You can also enable debug output by changing the factory line to code like this

https://github.com/oberstet/Autobahn/blob/master/demo/echo/echo_server_with_logging.py#L50

2 more notes:

- you don't need the sync = True option (it's really an advanced option .. mostly used with the Autobahn WS testsuite)
- you might wanna join http://groups.google.com/group/autobahnws .. get answers more quickly .. I discovered your Q only by accident here

Disclosure: I am author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually just found out the issue (answer above).  I'll take off the sync=True option - not sure where I got it.